# Can't pull other users Commits from Remote Repository - GIT

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGIT and Windows XP and we've set up a remote repository on a shared Network drive.

There's two of us in the team and my colleague can push/pull his own commits just fine (but can't see any of mine).If i clone the remote repository on to my machine, i can't see any of his commits, only the ones i've committed.

We're both working on the master branch.

I'm totally stumped as to what this problem is. Any ideas to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the log with command-line instead of TortoiseGit? in a command prompt, navigate under repository's directory and run `git log --pretty=format:'%h by %an'`

Comment: Thanks that helped. Can see some of his changes now, but  not all of them

Comment: There is a problem in what you describe: you can't push your commits on the same branch of the same repo without pulling and then seeing other commits.

Comment: So to do it properly, every time i want to push to the shared repo, i first commit to my repo, pull from the remote, and then push back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git fetch`. Then take a look at all branches by adding the `--all` modifier to either `gitk` or `git log`. At this point you can merge or rebase your changes with what's on the server. Only after you do that will you be able to push your changes.

Answer (score 1):

If a fresh clone of the repository shows only your commits, that means that your colleague is not pushing his changes correctly. Maybe there is something in the way blocking the push, e.g. unresolved merges or conflicts.